# In "Seinfeld" season 2 certain jobs are considered "a union thing" which makes them difficult to get. Why is that?

Tags: seinfeld

One of the characters in a TV show "Seinfeld", season 2, episode 12 (1991) is considering his career options and rejects projectionist and a stable boy as possible choices, because they probably are "a union thing". I understand it means something about labor unions. What exactly makes these jobs inaccessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a well-known joke, based on a '[Catch 22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic))' premise, known as '[closed-shop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_shop)'.

> You can't work in a union job unless you are a member of the union.
>
> You cannot join the union until you have proof you have worked in that
>   job.

This used to be often said about the UK actors' union, [Equity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equity_(trade_union)), until the law was changed to outlaw 'closed-shop'.